# How to remove [[ , , , , ]] in my Android code

Tags: java, android, random

I need to remove the `[[, , , ,]]` in my output of generated random numbers.

My code follows:

```
@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

    final Random myRandom = new Random();

    Button buttonGenerate = (Button)findViewById(R.id.generateme);
    final TextView textGenerateNumber = (TextView)findViewById(R.id.generatenumber);

    buttonGenerate.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener(){
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            ArrayList<Object> Arry1 = new ArrayList<Object>();
            for(int i=0;i<1;i++){
                ArrayList<Integer> Arry = new ArrayList<Integer>();
                for(int k=0;k<7;k++){
                    Arry.add(myRandom.nextInt(10));
                }
                Arry1.add(Arry);
            }
            textGenerateNumber.setText(String.valueOf(Arry1));
        }
    });  
}
```

[image: here is the output on the emulator]

Comment: What do you want to see?

Comment: Just do a 'for'-loop and print out the numbers one by one?

Comment: Why are you making an ArrayList of ArrayLists?

Comment: @baraky i just want to see numbers only.. how to do that?

Comment: For one time execution why are you using: for(int i=0;i<1;i++)

Comment: @tjameson i just refer to some code to generate 7 random numbers, now i want only numbers to be shown, how to do that?

Comment: I just want to know the symantics of your code first. If it's a List<List>, then that's different than a single list. Your code uses a single list, but if that's just an example (could be a list of more than one list), then there may be concerns about what order to print the numbers.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your code doesn't make any sense, so I suggest you read more (and check examples) about java variable types and Arrays.

For what you ask, you can use:

```
     @Override
     public void onClick(View v) {
         String text = "";
         for(int k=0;k<6;k++){
             text += myRandom.nextInt(10)) + " ";
         }
         text += myRandom.nextInt(10))
         textGenerateNumber.setText(text);
     }
```

This will output all the numbers space separated

Answer (score 0):

```
StringBuilder builder = new StringBuilder();
for(Integer i : Arry) {
    builder.append(i);
}
textGenerateNumber.setText(builder.toString());
```

Comment: you do realize you don't use your builder and the result is exactly the same ?

Answer (score 0):

Change your Random gen code to :

```
               String rand = "";

               for(int k=0;k<7;k++){
                   rand += myRandom.nextInt(10);
               }                       

               textGenerateNumber.setText(rand);
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use a simple logic -

```
String concat ="";
for(int i = 0;i<Arry1.length;i++)
{
   concat = concat + Arry1[i];
}
```

before

```
textGenerateNumber.setText(concat);
```

Hope this can help you.

Comment: why do people keep reinventing the wheel ? 1/ fast-enum is so much nicer than looping on the array index. 2/ TextUtils.join does all that in 1 call.

Answer (score 0):

```
buttonGenerate.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
    @Override
    public void onClick(View v) {
        StringBuilder builder = new StringBuilder();

        for (int k = 0; k < 6; k++) {
            builder.append(myRandom.nextInt(10));
            builder.append(" ");
        }

        builder.append(myRandom.nextInt(10));

        textGenerateNumber.setText(builder.toString());
    }
});
```

Comment: reinventing the wheel (textutils.join, in this case)

Answer (score 0):

You can use`replaceAll("\\[", "").replaceAll("\\]","").replace(",", "");` as shown below

```
@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

    final Random myRandom = new Random();

    Button buttonGenerate = (Button)findViewById(R.id.generateme);
    final TextView textGenerateNumber = (TextView)findViewById(R.id.generatenumber);

    buttonGenerate.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener(){
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            ArrayList<Object> Arry1 = new ArrayList<Object>();
            for(int i=0;i<1;i++){
                ArrayList<Integer> Arry = new ArrayList<Integer>();
                for(int k=0;k<7;k++){
                    Arry.add(myRandom.nextInt(10));
                }
                Arry1.add(Arry);
            }

            String value = String.valueOf(Arry1);//changes here
            value = value.replaceAll("\\[", "").replaceAll("\\]","").replace(",", "");//changes here

            textGenerateNumber.setText(value );
        }
    });  
}
```

Comment: @100kg : exactly. that's merely a hack. while it does answer the question, it is a very bad practice (to mention only 1 drawback : it depends on the actual format of the valueOf)

Answer (score 0):

There is a dedicated method in Android for that, TextUtils.join.

I will not duplicate the doumentation, but in short it formats lists and arrays by joining them with a link string.

Typically,

```
int[] ints = new int[] {1, 2, 3, 4}
Log.d("", TextUtils.join(ints, " - "));
```

results in

```
1 - 2 - 3 - 4
```

Answer (score -1):

So just print the numbers one by one

```
 @Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

    final Random myRandom = new Random();


     Button buttonGenerate = (Button)findViewById(R.id.generateme);
    final TextView textGenerateNumber = (TextView)findViewById(R.id.generatenumber);

    buttonGenerate.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener(){

             @Override
             public void onClick(View v) {
                 ArrayList<Object> Arry1 = new ArrayList<Object>();
                    for(int i=0;i<1;i++){
                   ArrayList<Integer> Arry = new ArrayList<Integer>();
                   for(int k=0;k<7;k++){
                       textGenerateNumber.setText(myRandom.nextInt(10));
                   }
                       Arry1.add(Arry);
                   }

                       }
                       });  
                    }
                 }
```

Comment: wrong answer, and will result in only the last number being shown.